# Using $.ajaxStop() to determine when page is finished loading in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, phantomjs, casperjs

So far in my tests written in CasperJS, I've been using waitForSelector() on page-specific elements to determine if a page has fully loaded (including all the async ajax requests). I was hoping to come up with a more standard way of waiting for page load and was wondering if the following was possible?

1. Inject as clientscript the following (include.js)

   ```
   $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
       // Do something
   })
   ```

Description of ajaxStop according to jquery api: Register a handler to be called when all Ajax requests have completed.

2. Define a casper.waitForLoad function that when called would wait for the "something" in above code block
3. Use the function in several parts of the test.

Also any tips on the // Do Something part would also be appreciated :) I was thinking about using the window.callPhantom feature in phantomJS but I'm reading that it's not officially supported in casperjs.

Comment: Also, is it possible to wait within the phantom/casper evaluate function for a callback to resolve using jQuery's Deferred object? Something like:
  request = page.evaluate ->
   deferred = $.Deferred
   $.ajaxStop(deferred.resolve)
   return deferred.promise

Sorry if the syntax is not accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this in include.js:

```
(function(){
    window._allAjaxRequestsHaveStopped = false;
    var interval;
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        if (interval) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = null;
        }
        interval = setTimeout(function(){
            window._allAjaxRequestsHaveStopped = true;
        }, 500);
    });
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        window._allAjaxRequestsHaveStopped = false;
        if (interval) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = null;
        }
    });
})();
```

This sets a (hopefully unique) variable to the `window` object that can be later retrieved. This also waits a little longer incase there is another request after the previous batch ended.

In CasperJS you would probably do something like the following to wait for the change in the request status. This uses adds a new function to the `casper` object and uses `casper.waitFor()` internally to check the change.

```
casper.waitForAjaxStop = function(then, onTimeout, timeout){
    return this.waitFor(function(){
        return this.evaluate(function(){
            return window._allAjaxRequestsHaveStopped;
        });
    }, then, onTimeout, timeout);
};
```

And use it like this:

```
casper.start(url).waitForAjaxStop().then(function(){
    // do something
}).run();
```

or this:

```
casper.start(url).thenClick(selector).waitForAjaxStop().then(function(){
    // do something
}).run();
```

Comment: Thank you! Really small question: I wrote an include.js which set a variable without explicitly putting it in the window context and I was able to retrieve it fine late using casper.evaluate(). Are those variables by default in the window scope? AFAIK there is no global scope past the window scope.

Comment: Yes, they are. A variable that is declared outside of all functions is in the global scope and in the browser that means in the `window` object.

Comment: Where does casperjs inject the javascript? For example, when dealing with single page applications built in javascript that just re render the body content, could the injected javascript be deleted?

Comment: Yes, sure. `casper.evaluate(function(){ delete window.__utils__; delete window.callPhantom;});` removes all traces of PhantomJS and CasperJS involvement if for example the page wants to check in which browser it is executed. Note that if you do this, most CasperJS functions won't work anymore.

Comment: Ah but it won't be deleted automatically right? I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem in which ajaxStop / ajaxStart sometimes don't get called.

Comment: Also how could I duplicate this for events rather than ajax calls? Right now I have something similar setup within casper.on(remote.message) but since casperjs adds the steps to a stack, i cant really reset it like the way you reset interval in the code above. I've tried deleting the last step but that seems to lead to unexpected behaviors like deleting a step that was just added in the actual test flow.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly. Do you want to wait for native CasperJS events? I think I answered such a question in the past.

Comment: oh no i meant the events that you see in the browser javascript console which you could monitor with casper.on(remote.message).
But before that I think i found out the problem. When I inject the include.js, sometimes it doesn't load the full file. For example i could add a console.log just before the ajaxStop() which would always output but if I add a console.log after ajaxStart(), it will only output sometimes. How can I make sure the script is fully loaded?

Comment: I haven't used `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` myself. I just looked at the documentation thought `ajaxStart` would fire again if a new ajax request is sent after `ajaxStop` fired. I guess I was wrong, but the `ajaxStart` part of my code is only meant as a fallback. You can always increase the `setTimeout` delay.

Comment: Yea never mind it did work as you thought since it still fired if there were no ongoing ajax requests. Do you have any idea why the include may not be getting fully loaded (the jquery functions) sometimes?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "include", if you use PhantomJS' `includeJs()`, then you're probably breaking out of the CasperJS control flow. Use `casper.options.remoteScripts` instead.

Comment: I've been doing casper.options.clientScripts.push('./include.js') at the start of the code. I should use clientScripts when I have direct file path right? I know the script is getting injected, just that not all of it is loading sometimes for some reason.

Comment: Yes. Client script evaluation is instantaneous. Ask a new question if you can't solve it. Comments are not the right place to do this.