# CasperJS injected client javascript not being loaded fully?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm currently injecting a include.js using

```
casper.options.clientScripts.push('./include.js')
```

Here's include.js (it's to make sure all ajax requests are completed: [Using $.ajaxStop() to determine when page is finished loading in CasperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986078/using-ajaxstop-to-determine-when-page-is-finished-loading-in-casperjs))

```
(function(){
    window._allAjaxRequestsHaveStopped = false;
    var interval;
    console.log('injecting include js')
    $.ajaxSetup({'global':true});
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        console.log('NO MORE outstanding ajax calls');
        if (interval) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = null;
        }
        interval = setTimeout(function() {
            window._allAjaxRequestsHaveStopped = true;
        }, 1000);
    });
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        console.log('NEW ajax call');
        if (interval) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = null;
        }
    });
    console.log('include js loaded');
})();
```

The problem is that sometimes the ajaxStop & ajaxStart functions just won't get loaded but it always outputs the first console.log 'injecting include js'.

CasperJS script

```
casper.waitForAjax = (callback) ->
    fn_wait = ->
        casper.evaluate ->
            return window._allAjaxRequestsHaveStopped

    casper.waitFor fn_wait, callback

casper.options.clientScripts.push('./include.js')
casper.options.waitTimeout = 10000

describe 'Main Test', ->
    before ->
        casper.start 'url', ->
            phantom.clearCookies()

    it 'Test Case 1', ->
        casper.then ->
            @click 'button' 
        casper.waitForAjax ->
            // Move on with test
```

So sometimes my code will time out waiting for window._allAjaxRequestsHaveStopped to turn true while other times it would work fine. I'm also testing on the same page that I know has ajax requests. Does anyone know how to fix this inconsistency?

Answer (score 0):

Got it! So where it seemed only part of the script was being loaded, there really was an error as soon as it got to $(document).ajaxStop() since jQuery wasn't loaded on the page yet. CasperJS sometimes injected the include file after jQuery was loaded, and that's why it was working sometimes.

Fixed it by downloading jQuery and manually injecting it before include file:

```
casper.options.clientScripts.push('./jquery-2.1.4.min.js')
casper.options.clientScripts.push('./include.js')
```